# Customizing graph parameters not explicitly listed as function arguments of enrichplot::treeplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, rna-seq

I have been trying to create a figure using enrichplot::treeplot(), and I cannot figure out how to make additional modifications to the graph created by treeplot().  I pasted the example code/dataset below that reproduces the example figure.

When I apply this to my data (it is also evident in the example) the pathway names (which are quite long) are in a large enough font that it crowds the figure.  Also, when too many pathways are shown, the text overlaps.

I have manipulated all of the arguments listed in ?treeplots(), however none of them modify the fontsize of the pathway names. (the font argument modifies the pairwise terms listed to the right of the pathways)

While I'm focusing on the font size here, my question is more generalizable - is there a way to make further modifications of graphs in R beyond what is made available in the function arguments? I understand there is the "..." listed in most(all?) graphing functions, however despite my efforts I do not understand how to use that to pass arguments to another function, if that is indeed how one may modify graphs.

If this could be answered through a tutorial already posted somewhere I would be so grateful, I've been teaching myself how to use R for sequencing analysis for some time now, but I have not gotten very good at customizing graphs unless the function makes it very simple to do.

```
#Using the example code and data 
#https://yulab-smu.top/biomedical-knowledge-mining-book/enrichplot.html

install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("DOSE")
BiocManager::install("enrichplot")

library(DOSE)
library(enrichplot)
data(geneList)

de <- names(geneList)[abs(geneList) > 2]
edo <- DOSE::enrichDGN(de)
edox <- DOSE::setReadable(edo, 'org.Hs.eg.db', 'ENTREZID')
edox2 <- enrichplot::pairwise_termsim(edox)

p1 <- treeplot(edox2)
p1
```

[image: Link to example graph on the left, and what my data graphed looks like on the right]

Comment: are those packages on CRAN?

Comment: No they are on bioconductor, i edited the code to reflect the install, totally forgot that.

Answer (score 1):

This plot is made via `ggplot`, and essentially you can make the text relatively smaller simply by increasing the plotting window size.

When I run your code I get something like this:

```r
p1
```

[image]

But if I drag the window to make it larger, I get:

[image]

Because the output is a `ggplot` object, you can reach into the layers to change the parameters of the layers. For example, to make the cancer labels smaller, even at the default plot size, you can do:

```r
p1$layers[[7]]$aes_params$size <- 2
p1
```

[image]

There are also options in the `treeplot` function to change some of the label sizes, scales, etc, but as with many ggplot2 wrappers, the customization is limited in order to reduce the number of parameters in the function. The idea is that it is easier for the end-user to get a presentable plot, but that comes at a cost of reduced customization.

Comment: Allen, I cannot thank you enough!  As a bench scientist forced into this I've struggled to teach myself how to use seq analysis packages...  Understanding how to adjust plots has been one of the hardest aspects.  I'm so ignorant I didnt understand something as simple as dragging the plot window.   I didn't know how to access ggplot layers like you showed, but now I think I can run with that and customize further.  I spent hours on this with no success, I am so grateful thank you.    
If you don't mind sparing more of your wisdom, is graph customization ever done with the "..." arguments?

Comment: You're welcome Clay. From looking at the source code, the `...` arguments are simply ignored. They are not put to use inside the function, so can have no effect on the finished plot. The customization options are limited to the parameters listed in the help file (or hacking the plot after it is created as I show above)

Comment: Ok, so that was something i wasn't sure of, when i looked at it i didnt see anything calling for ```...``` inside the definition of the function, but I wasn't sure if i was still missing some basic concept of how to use them.  Guess that means if they dont appear in the function then its a scenario like this, and i suppose in a function that uses them, looking at the code might give some insight as to how.

Comment: @ClaySandel exactly. You will either see the dots passed on to another function, or occasionally captured as a list and used in some other way. Neither occurs in this function.

Comment: @AllenCameron 
Do you know of any in depth resource that can help dissect ggplot2 wrappers to edit them for customization?
I have been trying to 'hack' gseaplot2 objects to customize appearances.  I've been  following what you showed me with the treeplot - exploring what is inside  p$layers, p[[1]]$layers, but there's a deep complexity with some of these objects, and making edits to parameters often does not have the assumed effect 
i have succeeded in editing x-axis limits and ticks with much trial-and-error.